# Vector to string, save in file and again to vector? Python

Tags: python, string, vector

this is my first question, sorry for my english.

I have already search, but hmm, i didn't know how to search and i try different ways and keywords, but nothing.

The problem is this:

I'm doing some scripts in blender with python and i want to use config parser to save and load items, etc. But for example if i want to save a color, that in blender is a Vector of 4 float places, putting the vector in a file with config parser, it obviusly save a string in the file, Example (variable config is all the config parser stuff):

```
vector_color = [ 0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0 ]
config.set("section", "item", vector_color)
```

it's gonna save this:

> [section]
>   item = <Vector (0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0)>

such is a good thing because it stores the vector, but now.. the problem, i want to load the vector, and how i can do that? thats my question, because if i load it like a vector, it is a string, so.. how i can convert it again to vector? i prove with eval(), literal_eval(), config.read_string(), i don't know i prove with many probably functions.

so, with less words:

how i can convert this string:

```
"<Vector (0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0)>"
```

to this vector

```
[0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save the actual object - save a *list* instead of a file with the characters "[1, 2, 3]" in it - I would highly recommend looking at `pickle`.

```
import pickle

my_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
pickled_list = pickle.dumps(my_list)
f = open('my_file.py', 'w')
f.write(pickled_list)
f.close()

#a wild coding appears...
#you used python... it's super effective

f = open('my_file.py', 'r')
read_file = f.read()
my_loaded_list = pickle.loads(read_file)
f.close()

my_loaded_list ##should be the list you just saved
```

'pickle' is great. Check the official Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex, like so:

```
import re

s = "<Vector (0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0)>"
v = [float(x.group()) for x in re.finditer('\d.\d', s)]

# v = [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 1.0]
```